# Angular2 using the hash in routing fails

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

From the docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles

Ive added

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
  ];

 @NgModule({
  imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }) //added this useHash
   ],
   exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
    } )
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

But am now getting an error that `node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'ROUTER_PROVIDERS'`  and the error points to the line on useHash

THESE ARE THE IMPORTS IN THE APP MODULE

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 FormsModule,
 HttpModule,
 AppRoutingModule, //CONTAINS THE ABOVE ROUTING
 AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

],
```

Where am i wrong or what more do i need to add for this to work

Comment: You are using an older router version

Comment: I just ceated a new project a few minutes with angular2 cli so i believe this is not an old router version

Comment: Can you share your imports? And do you use `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Ive added the imports ive not used router providers

Comment: Ehm my bad, by imports I meant like `import { RouterModule } from ..`

Comment: Oh i see when trying various ways of implementing # i imported this even though its not being used anywhere after removing it now works thanks